# How to raise code review for some class out of many class in my package?

Tags: git, tfs-code-review

I have a **master** branch which I kept clean and I cut a branch **dev** from there. this is the branch currently I am working on.
I have 20 classes on this branch in my package and I have to raise the CR for 5 classes only. How can I do that?

for now what I am doing,

I made a branch named **test** from master.

```
git branch test
git checkout test
```

bringing my code from dev branch to test branch in one commit.

```
git merge --squash dev
```

here I have all the files in staging area.
Removing 15 classes from staging area and keeping only 5 for which I have to raise the CR.

```
    git restore --staged <filename1>
    .
    .
    git restore --staged <filename15>
```

after removing 15 files, commiting and raising CR for remaining 5 files.

Answer (score 0):

You could also:

- switch to your test branch
- copy 5 files from dev to test:

That is:

```
git switch test
git restore --source=dev --staged --worktree file1
git restore --source=dev --staged --worktree file2
...
git commit -m "Add 5 files"
```

Comment: my code is in dev branch...test branch I created for commit purpose.

Comment: read again, I made little modification to make it more readable

Comment: @AkashPatel The idea remains the same: you can copy files from one branch to another. I have updated the answer accordingly.